# Dispatch an action in redux

Tags: redux

I created an app which should simulate the buying of products. So, when i will click on the `BUY` button, the number of fruits should decrement.
I suppose that the problem is in my reducer, but i can' t understand where.

```js
/////
const Fruits = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  return (
      <div>
        <h1>Number of fruits: {props.numFruits} </h1>
        <button onClick={buyFruitsAction}>BUY</button>
      </div>
  );
};
const mapStateToProps=(state)=> {
  return {
    numFruits: state.numFruits
  }
};
const mapDispatchToProps=(dispatch)=> {
  return {
    buyFruitsAction: ()=> dispatch(buyFruitsAction())
  }
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Fruits)


//// Reducer

import {BUY_FRUITS} from "../types";

const initialState = {
  numFruits : 10
};
 const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case BUY_FRUITS : return {
      ...state,
      numFruits: state.numFruits - 1
    };
    default: return state;
  }
};
 export default reducer;
```

Where is the issue of my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is the problem:

```
<button onClick={buyFruitsAction}>BUY</button>
```

There is no variable `buyFruitsAction`, it is a property. So that should read `props.buyFruitsAction`.

Answer (score 0):

Your reducer is fine, can you post your action creator?

buyFruitsAction is undefined in your component do you meant props.buyFruitsAction?